# Bitbucket pipeline exists without running step in definitions

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

Here is my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`

pipeline runs without any errors. but `<<: *build_and_deploy` is not running in `tags:`
how can I run `git checkout -b master` and code in `*build_and_deploy` with `deployment: Production`

Basically, I want to use the same steps for the different deployment environments.
Also, in the pipeline, we can't use the same deployment multiple times.

```html
# Variables:
#     Repository:
#         - NETLIFY_AUTH_TOKEN
#     Deployments:
#         - NETLIFY_SITE_ID
image: node:14.21.3

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build_and_deploy
        caches:
          - node
        name: "Build and Deploy"
        size: 2x
        script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
          - npm run deploy

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build and Deploy develop branch
          deployment: Development
          <<: *build_and_deploy

  tags:
    "*.*.*":
      - step:
          name: Build and Deploy master branch on tag
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - git checkout -b master
          <<: *build_and_deploy
```

Update 1:
When tags get created, I want to switch to the master branch and run build and depoly commands.

Comment: I'm confused a little bit for your situation, I couldn't understand the exact problem. as far as I understood, you want your tagged deployment consists master branch's code right? then why not use `branches: master:` for it? Apart from that you can tag your master branch's code via git commands and also via Bitbucket Pipelines UI. Can you elaborate your question a little bit more so I can provide you a proper bitbucket-pipelines.yml for it.

Comment: okay, we use master branch for stage env. when we want to move it to prod we tag latest commit to master branch with version number. once we tag i want pipeline to switch to master branch and perform build_and_deploy.

Comment: I am also still confused about the phrasing. What do you mean with "when tags get created, I want to switch to the master branch"? You want to run the pipeline on the commit that was tagged, don't you?